# HP UFT 12.52 An error has occurred

Tags: hp-uft

I am using HP UFT 12.52 with a valid Seat license. It used to work fine earlier but since the past few days, it throws an error dialog with just one sentence "An error has occurred" in it whenever I open UFT or Create/Save a new test. There is no other details.

Has anyone experienced this/ solved this issue? TIA.

Comment: I think it is best to ask HP Support

Comment: Run a repair install from Control Panels

Comment: Does it keep happening after a reboot?   Do you also have a lot of Chrome tabs open?   My current project in QTP is so big, I run my poor laptop out of ram probably at least once a day... and that's what I see when it happens.   Though, my "An error has occurred" is usually accompanied by LOTS of trace data...

Comment: repair install has worked for now. thank you